# How to filter rows only if a string matches for multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I would like to filter rows only if a string matches for multiple columns. I looked for answer but I didn't find it. I guess that I don't exactly know what to look for.

So, let say I have a tibble like this.

```
library(tibble)
tib1 <- tibble(ID = 1:3, Col.1 = c("Hi", "Hello", "ND"), Col.2 = c("Bye", "ND", "ND"))
tib1


# A tibble: 3 x 3
     ID Col.1 Col.2
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Hi    Bye  
2     2 Hello ND   
3     3 ND    ND
```

I would like to know how to get this return.

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     ID Col.1 Col.2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     3 ND    ND
```

I tried some code line as follow, but it always return all the rows that have a single match for the string.

```
tib1 %>% filter_at(vars(Col.1, Col.2), any_vars(str_detect(., "ND")))

# A tibble: 2 x 3
     ID Col.1 Col.2
  <int> <chr> <chr>
1     2 Hello ND   
2     3 ND    ND
```

How can I do that? I would like to do it with the tidyverse packages.

Thank you and have a good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give your desired output - changing `any_vars` to `all_vars` which changes the predicate from an `|` to `&`.

```
tib1 %>% 
  filter_at(vars(Col.1, Col.2), all_vars(str_detect(., "ND")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
has_multiple <- function(s, v) {
  
  occurrences <- v == s
  sum(occurrences) > 1
    
}

tib1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(has_multiple('ND', c_across(Col.1:Col.2)))
```

@EJJ's answer will return rows where *all* variables are 'ND'.

My code returns rows where *two or more* (but not necessarily all) variables are 'ND'.

Of course, in this example, with ony two variables, the result is the same.